# How to physically connect "thin" clients to the server/host

Tags: rds, thin-client

In this setup, the server will running Windows Server 2008 and will be handling all of the workload and running the programs and the clients will use the remote desktop services to connect. I was wondering if I need to connect every client PC to the server via ethernet cable or if the clients can use a wireless connection to connect? Which one is more ideal if both are possible? The biggest reason for the question is because some of the client PC's will be difficult to run an ethernet cable to and from and if there are no major problems with connecting wireless then we may go that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wireless thin clients exist.](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF05a/12454-12454-321959-338927-3640406-5226831.html?dnr=2) Wireless cards for PCs are also available.

Provided your wireless infrastructure is equipped to provide good coverage throughout your facility, these are an option for RDS connections back to your server.

Comment: Ok, so is connecting via ethernet really just a stability thing?

Comment: Stability and performance. Planning a good wifi infrastructure takes some design effort and can also be costly.

Comment: Which is why most of us would seriously prefer to use a wired connection. Wireless is nice, but the moment you have 100 connections running - and that can happen fast - things are not really nice anymore. Not unless you planned a lot and invested a lot.

Comment: Yes, I am planning on "restructuring" the wifi infrastructure soon as well and is something that I will have to look in to as well. Thank you for your answer, since I am a beginner, I was mostly curious if it was possible to connect wireless and if there were any "unwritten rules" or major reasons against connecting a PC wirelessly to the server.

Comment: I will try to avoid using a wireless connection if possible but it seems logical that any laptops connecting would most likely be wirelessly connected.